# Python disable console in program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console

I made a console game in python, and I would like to disable the console when it prints the story. It looks like this:

```
print("First line of story")
time.sleep(2)
print("Second line of story")
time.sleep(2)
```

And so on...

So my problem is that the player can type and mess up with the console while it's writing the story. Can I disable the typing somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix, you can disable echoing like this:

```
import sys
import termios
import time

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
new = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
new[3] &= ~termios.ECHO

termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)

print("First line of story")
time.sleep(2)
print("Second line of story")
time.sleep(2)

termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
```

If you don't want the suppressed input to be echoed after the last `tcsetattr` call, you can substitute the last `TCSADRAIN` with `TCSAFLUSH`.

Documentation for the termios module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/termios.html), which is also where the example is taken from.